# Magento:products images are not displaying on New store

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I created sub-store and displayed all products on all new stores as:
Go to your manage products page, click select all, change the action dropdown to say "Change Attributes" and click submit. Then, on the websites tab, make sure your new site is checked in the "Add Product to Websites" area, and click save.

Requirement: All set well but products images are not displaying same like main website.Hoe to display images on product-list and product-detail pages?

Comment: have you set the proper base category under the website section, configuration -> stores

Comment: All stores are sharing same base category thats why all products are categories are displaying on all stores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer so posting here too. I changed the media directory permission to 777 and issue fixed. It can help someone :)

Comment: Please accept your answer if the issue solved if you are not aware of how to accept the answer see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/276519)

Answer (score 0):

1) Most probably your images are not set for the new website. Maybe you set the images per website and not use the default values. In that case go to the images tab for a particular product and either click use default values or make the settings like on other stores.

2) If you use an extension for displaying images go to the settings of that extension and check it for the new website.

3) To further debug just change the directory name of your theme in skin and app (from example to _example) to load the base theme and see if it is something related to your theme or not.

Comment: To display products on all sub-store, I used above steps. ie i edited mass-products and there is no option of images to update and its not possible for me to update each product because there are around 1200 products. please suggest another solution.

Comment: ...I still could not succeed in image display.can you please suggest more suggestion?

Comment: @Jai Did you find what the issue is? You can try changing values with a magmi import

Comment: ..First, thanks for your help for all topics and i think its just some configuration issue or can it be because of mass-edit products assign to all store-views?
magmi is not seems to be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this type problem as

```
step-1:
changed the media directory permission to 777

Step-2:
Delete media .htaccess (media/.htaccess).Must be take backup of .htaccess
```